# How to allow user to preserve environment with sudo?

Tags: sudo, sudoers

I'm running into the following error trying to allow some environment variables to pass through to the new environment when running `sudo`:

```
sudo: sorry, you are not allowed to preserve the environment
```

Some information that may be helpful to debug:

```
[deploy@worker1 ~]$ sudo -l
    Matching Defaults entries for deploy on this host:
    requiretty, !visiblepw, always_set_home, env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS", env_keep+="MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE",
    env_keep+="LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES", env_keep+="LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE", env_keep+="LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET
    XAUTHORITY", secure_path=/sbin\:/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin, env_keep+="GIT_WORK_TREE GIT_DIR", !requiretty

User deploy may run the following commands on this host:
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/git, (ALL) /etc/init.d/httpd*, (ALL) /sbin/service, (ALL) /usr/bin/make, (ALL) /bin/echo
```

My running example:

```
[deploy@worker1 ~]$ export GIT_DIR="/home/ashinn/testing"
[deploy@worker1 ~]$ sudo -E sh -c 'echo "$GIT_DIR"'
sudo: sorry, you are not allowed to preserve the environment
```

My sudoers.d file for this specific configuration:

```
Defaults:deploy         env_keep += "GIT_WORK_TREE GIT_DIR", !requiretty
deploy  ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/git, /etc/init.d/httpd*, /sbin/service, /usr/bin/make, /bin/echo
```

I've also tried adding `!env_reset` to the Defaults and it still fails with the same error. I feel like I may be missing something obvious and need a second set of eyes. What am I missing here?

Comment: I believe that approximately 93% of us understand the point of your question, but your example command isn't very good.  `sudo ` *`(option(s)) `* `echo $GIT_DIR`, if it doesn't fail outright, will display the pre-`sudo` value of `$GIT_DIR`, because the shell expands the variable in the command line before `sudo` is even invoked.  Better tests are `sudo printenv GIT_DIR` or `sudo env | grep GIT_DIR` or `sudo sh -c 'echo "$GIT_DIR"'`, where we're actually looking at the environment of the process that's running privileged.

Comment: See also [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can use the `SETENV` "Tag" in your `sudoers` file, as in :

```
deploy  ALL=(ALL)       SETENV: /usr/bin/git, /etc/init.d/httpd*, /sbin/service, /usr/bin/make, /bin/echo
```

Or, to combine it with NOPASSWD:

```
deploy  ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD:SETENV: /usr/bin/git, /etc/init.d/httpd*, /sbin/service, /usr/bin/make, /bin/echo
```

Relevant excerpt from the sudoers man :

> #### SETENV and NOSETENV
>
> These tags override the value of the setenv option on a per-command basis. Note that if SETENV has been set for a command, the user may disable the env_reset option from the command line via the -E option. Additionally, environment variables set on the command line are not subject to the restrictions imposed by `env_check`, `env_delete`, or `env_keep`. As such, only trusted users should be allowed to set variables in this manner. If the command matched is ALL, the SETENV tag is implied for that command; this default may be overridden by use of the NOSETENV tag.

Comment: It's unbelievable how many useless answers are out there for this very same question. ```SETENV:``` did the trick for me. Thank you

Comment: this is the only solution that works for me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Don’t specify the `-E` option. Using `-E` you´re saying that all the environment variables for the user `deploy` should be preserved, not only `GIT_DIR`

Running `sudo echo $GIT_DIR` should work because you've added `GIT_DIR` to the `env_keep` list